# How to autostart Popcorn jPlayer plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, jplayer, popcornjs

I've created a player using jPlayer and the Popcorn jPlayer plugin. The setup is this:

```
 var $player = Popcorn
                   .jplayer('#jquery_jplayer_1', {
                        media: {
                            m4v: Content.videoURL,
                            poster:  Content.posterURL
                        },
                        options: {
                            swfPath: "swf",
                            supplied: "m4v",
                            size: {
                                width: "640px",
                                height: "360px",
                                cssClass: "jp-video-360p"
                            },
                            smoothPlayBar: true,
                            keyEnabled: true
                        }
                    });
```

How can I autostart the player once the media is ready? Can I do this with the $player reference?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Add a ready function property to the options:

```
var $player = Popcorn
               .jplayer('#jquery_jplayer_1', {
                    media: {
                        m4v: Content.videoURL,
                        poster:  Content.posterURL
                    },
                    options: {
                        ready: function() {
                            $player.play();
                        },
                        swfPath: "swf",
                        supplied: "m4v",
                        size: {
                            width: "640px",
                            height: "360px",
                            cssClass: "jp-video-360p"
                        },
                        smoothPlayBar: true,
                        keyEnabled: true
                    }
                });
```